# R.keras error during call to fit function

Tags: r, keras

I am new to R keras, so please bear with me. I am trying to build a simple model using variables that are categorical, but I've recast as numeric.

I can get examples working from various tutorials in R/keras with my current installation so I know its not in reticulate or tensorflow or even R. However, when I try to use my own data to create the simple model, I obtain the following errors during the "fit" execution:

I'm pretty sure its my training data format, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going wrong. Thank you kindly in advance.

```
# Fit 
model_one <- model %>%   
+    fit(training, 
+        trainLabels, 
+        epochs = 100,
+        batch_size = 32, 
+        validation_split = 0.2)
```

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\JRM\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    C:\Users\JRM\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\JRM\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\JRM\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\JRM\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:533 train_step  **
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regulari
```

I've upload my script and sample data file to github:

[Sample Data and Script to reproduce error](https://github.com/jrmckenna/for_stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, found the error:

One hot encoding  generates a 2 column matrix:

```
# One hot encoding 
trainLabels <- to_categorical(trainingtarget)
testLabels <- to_categorical(testtarget)
print(testLabels[1:10,])
```

and the model was expecting 3 columns.

I changed the model call to automatically accept the correct number of columns based on the variables instead:

```
model %>%  
layer_dense(units = 8, activation = 'relu', input_shape = ncol(test)) %>%   
layer_dense(units = ncol(trainLabels), activation = 'softmax')
```